# Tell RavenDB to ignore a property

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have a document model to store in RavenDB but I don't want to store a calculated property. How do I tell RavenDB to ignore this property?

In the below example I don't want to store `Duration`.

```
public class Build
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime FinishedAt { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan Duration { get { return StartedAt.Subtract(FinishedAt); }}
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just decorate the `Duration` property with `[JsonIgnore]` like this:

```
public class Build
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime FinishedAt { get; set; }

    [Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
    //[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore] // for RavenDB 3 and up
    public TimeSpan Duration { get { return StartedAt.Subtract(FinishedAt); }}
}
```

See more here: http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/advanced/custom-serialization

Comment: Side note: If this class is in -another- project (eg. AwesomeNamespace.Core), then this other project needs to either nuget package Newtonsoft.Json or RavenDb.Client. Basically, this attribute is from the Newtonsoft.Json library. This could change in the future, but at the time of me writing this comment .. that's the score.

Comment: "With version 2 of RavenDB you need to use the attributes from the Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json namespace instead of the Newtonsoft.Json namespace. The Newtonsoft.Json namespacewill be ignored." -- Taken from the comments on the above linked post.

Comment: RavenDB 3: Use `[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]` rather than `Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json` namespace. Seems, they have changed it since @ChadT's commented on v2.